# How can i retrieve data from many to many, for create my custom restful api on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, resources, pivot

I'm new here, so hope everything is ok. 
I'm trying to retrive data from my pivot table  for structure my api.
I'm building a search filter for audio tracks.
The idea is to make an api with all information about each track and than work with ajax.
In my db i have 3 tables: tracks, tags, tag_track:
inside my tag_track i have 2column:
track_id tag_id

I started making a resource in laravel called TrackResource.
and this is the return of the function toArray($request):

```
return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'url' => $this->url,
            'duration' => $this->duration,
     ];
```

this is my api route:

```
Route::get('/all-tracks', function () {
    return TrackResource::collection(Track::all());
});
```

What i would like to do is :

```
return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'url' => $this->url,
            'duration' => $this->duration,
            'tags'=>...
];
```

so that in my JSON i can see all the tags assigned for each track

```
data:[
      "id": 1,
      "title": "trackTest",
      "url": "q2yQyWGmwJP5hrD3CAECAEgmfeHfpzqimSqYF42N.mpga",
      "duration": "00:02:40",
      "tags":[tag1, tag2]
];
```

what i've done is this:

```
return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'url' => $this->url,
            'duration' => $this->duration,
            'tags' => $this->whenPivotLoadedAs('tags', 'tag_track', function () {
               return $this->tags->name;
            }),
];
```

My JSON response works for 'id', 'title', 'slug', 'duration' but not for tags.

Thank you to everyone advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update your `tags()` n:n relationship to include fields from pivot

```php
protected $with = ['tags']; // Include this to eager load the relation

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(...)->withPivot('name');
}
```

### Create a `TagResource`

```php
<?php
class TagResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,

            'name' => $this->pivot->name
        ];
    }
}
```

You may update the return as your likes.

### From within your `TrackResource`, include `TagResource` as collection

```php
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'title' => $this->title,
    'slug' => $this->slug,
    'url' => $this->url,
    'duration' => $this->duration,
    'tags' => TagResource::collection($this->tags) 
];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

On the `Track` model specify `$with` to return the relationships on a model every time it is queried.

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Track extends Model
    {
        /**
         * The relationships that should always be loaded.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $with = ['tags'];

        /**
         * Get the tags for the track.
         */
        public function tags()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first create many-to-many relation in model Track:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_track', 'track_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

And then in returned array it will be looking like this:

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'title' => $this->title,
    'slug' => $this->slug,
    'url' => $this->url,
    'duration' => $this->duration,
    'tags' => $this->tags->pluck('name')
];
```